# Select SUM(case when value1 =351 then 1 else 0 end) as value2 from table1

Tags: sql

my sql query is

```
Select SUM(case when value1 =351 then 1 else 0 end) as value2 from table1
```

The output will be 1 if value1 =351.

is it possible to write the query as

```
Select SUM(case when value1 =351 then Y else N end) as value2 from table1
```

to get the output as Y or N?

Comment: how can you apply sum for varchar type column o/p sum is for numeric values.?

Comment: What would the SUM of `'Y'+'N'+'N'` be? Or of `'Y'+'Y'+'N'` ?

Comment: why do you use SUM ? what do you wanna add ?

Comment: Your question is not exactly clear, since you seem to be asking for a way to `sum` string values.  So can you post some sample data and then the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use MAX instead:

```
Select MAX(case when value1 =351 then 'Y' else 'N' end) as value2 
from table1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN value1=351 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS value2 FROM table1
```

The parenthesis around the `CASE-WHEN-THEN-ELSE-END` are optional in this case.